# Looking for a better pattern for a visitor-IAsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, visitor-pattern, iasyncenumerable

Consider this snippet (much simplified than the original code):

```
    async IAsyncEnumerable<(DateTime, double)> GetSamplesAsync()
    {
       // ...

            var cbpool = new CallbackPool(
                HandleBool: (dt, b) => { },
                HandleDouble: (dt, d) =>
                {
                    yield return (dt, d);     //not allowed
                });

            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync(token))
            {
                this.Parse(cursor.Current, cbpool);
            }
    }

    private record CallbackPool(
        Action<DateTime, bool> HandleBool,
        Action<DateTime, double> HandleDouble
        );
```

Then, the below `Parse` is just a behavior-equivalent of the original.

```
    Random _rnd = new Random();
    void Parse(object cursor, CallbackPool cbpool)
    {
        double d = this._rnd.NextDouble();  //d = [0..1)
        if (d >= 0.5)
        {
            cbpool.HandleDouble(new DateTime(), d);
        }
        else if (d >= 0.25)
        {
            cbpool.HandleBool(new DateTime(), d >= 0.4);
        }
    }
```

However, I do like the `GetSamplesAsync` code, but the compiler does not: the `yield` cannot be used within a lambda.

So, I changed the function as follows, although it became much less readable (and also error-prone):

```
    async IAsyncEnumerable<(DateTime, double)> GetSamplesAsync()
    {
       // ...

            (DateTime, double) pair = default;
            bool flag = false;
            var cbpool = new CallbackPool(
                HandleBool: (dt, b) => { },
                HandleDouble: (dt, d) =>
                {
                    pair = (dt, d);
                    flag = true;
                });

            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync(token))
            {
                this.Parse(cursor.Current, cbpool);
                if (flag)
                {
                    yield return pair;
                }
                flag = false;
            }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a better way to solve this kind of pattern.

Comment: What is the type of the `cursor` variable?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias in the original code the cursor is a BsonDocument, enumerating a MongoDB collection. However, it does not matter for the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The external `flag`/`pair` is pretty dangerous and unnecessary (and it forces a closure); it seems like this `bool` could be *returned* from the `Parse` method, for example:

```cs
await foreach (var item in cursor)
{
    if (Parse(item, cbpool, out var result))
        yield return result;
}
```

(everything could also be returned via a value-tuple if you don't like the `out`)

Comment: I totally agree with you, Marc, but I should change the Parse signature. I'd like to know if there's a decent way by keeping the Parse as-is.

Comment: @MarioVernari you could add the result state onto the `CallbackPool`? not quite as clean as functional, but IMO cleaner than the captures

Comment: Yes, I can do it. Definitely better than the current solution. Do you have any point that explains the problems on the yield with lambdas?

Comment: That is the same in non-async too; basically, `yield` is not simple - that is a *huge* rewrite of the method (by the compiler) into a state machine, with `yield` being the state change; it has a tough enough job rewriting *one* method into an iterator, but rewriting two co-dependent methods withe the `yield` in the wrong one: not even remotely viable; see: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGALAbgFgAoElAZiwCYMBhDAbxIxa0pQA4MBJAQSgCeAOwDGAUSEBXMIgjAANnAA8ASyEwAfBgDicGADUI8yXCj9hIgBQBKZqybFWTjADMA9ggyW1MDCowAvBiY+H4YShgArBihKgDUcbaOzik42FgA7H5EySwAviR5QA== for what happens here.